# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: requires com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am struggling with  this problem when the application goes to run on the mobile phone HUAWEI ALE - 21 Android 6.0 API 23 . My application collapses and I take back those errors .

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: requires com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
[image]

W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
[image]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.efti.myapplication">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS_PRIVILEGED"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.WRITE_VOICEMAIL"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.READ_VOICEMAIL"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ALLOW_ANY_CODEC_FOR_PLAYBACK"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_INCALL_EXPERIENCE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <!-- We use this to disable the status bar buttons of home, back and recent
    during an incoming call. By doing so this allows us to not show the user
    is viewing the activity in full screen alert, on a fresh system/factory
    reset state of the app. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <!-- This tells the activity manager to not delay any of our activity
     start requests, even if they happen immediately after the user
     presses home. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STOP_APP_SWITCHES"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <!-- Permissions needed for badger count showing on launch icon. -->
    <!--for Samsung-->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE"/>
    <!--for htc-->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT"/>
    <!--for sony-->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE"/>
    <!--for apex-->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT"/>
    <!--for solid-->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE"/>
    <!--for huawei-->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <!--for ZUK-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE"/>
    <!--for OPPO-->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light"
        android:label=""
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LoginActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;
    private static final String EMAIL = "email";
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private LoginButton loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(EMAIL));
        // If you are using in a fragment, call loginButton.setFragment(this);

        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });



        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });





        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();


        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        // set the view now
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate user
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's a runtime permission, you need to request it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post images of source code. Firstly, members may want to compile and run your code to better understand what is wrong. Secondly, members may want to search for additional information on APIs that you are using. Helpful tips here: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers!

Comment: Don't add errors as images

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android permission doesn't work even if I have declared it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check permission and request permission as below:

Code example:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        "com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS")
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Permission is not granted
    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            "com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS")) {
        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
    } else {
        // No explanation needed; request the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{"com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_SETTINGS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_SETTINGS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
} else {
    // Permission has already been granted
}
```

For  more details, see: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: You pretty much just copy-pasted the code from the URL

Comment: @Zoe which is what you want in case the original source is no longer available

Comment: Yes, but you never explicitly state it's from the URL (incorrect attribution).

Comment: @Zoe, It looks you overlooked the details of answer, e.g. the quoted code from the URL actually already adapted to the question, and the original URL was mentioned in the end of the answer.