# Has stated that the permissions are still abnormal , java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: android

Why do I declare `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permission in `AndroidP`, but still report error when running `startForeground`

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: startForeground from pid=21105, uid=10028 requires android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE

[image]

The strange thing is that I have check permission, invalid

[image]

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53952742/8034839

Comment: The strange thing is that I have check permission, invalid

Comment: Try to go to settings->app permission, enable the ones you need.

Comment: Find the reason, Xiaomi mobile phone default notification is all closed, just open it, know it will be easier, thank you